# Build is invalid on testflight

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-image-crop-picker to make the build. Build is successfully created but while check it on test-flight it shows that build is invalid. Why is this happening?

Comment: need more information, maybe it is a missing right on your info.plist or something different

Comment: @SteveAlves i am using this in info.plist file

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Please allow usage of your photo library.</string>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

Comment: I found this solution  if you are not using Cocoapods

-- Click on project General tab
-- Under Deployment Info set Deployment Target to 8.0
-- Under Embedded Binaries click + and add RSKImageCropper.framework and 
   QBImagePicker.framework

Thanks